# Opening safari from a link in Safari from within app

Tags: ios, objective-c, hyperlink, safari, mobile-safari

Sorry to bother you with this question, but is Is it possible to have website links within your iOS app open in Safari on the user's iDevice? I don't want to use UIWebview, I want the Safari application to open from my app with the website link that I have given the user. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To open the link from Safari and not the web view, you need to implement this method:

```
 - (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
    {

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:SomeURL]]; 

return NO;

    }
```

Confirm to **UIWebViewDelegate**, and return "NO', (in case you want the web WebView to open it).

Comment: How do I apply this to a text link e.g. a UILabel?

Comment: You can't. You'd need a UITextView instead for this, which handles links to Safari :)

Answer (score 0):

Override shouldStartLoadWithRequest in your WebView like this :

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView*)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest*)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {
if ( navigationType == UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked ) {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[request URL]];
    return NO;
}
```